# How to fix my error with FBInstreamAdView

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

I want to implement facebook in-stream into my `iOS` app

I'm setting **FBInstreamAdView** with "**YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID**".

Then my app is crash.

I try to use this.

```
import FBAudienceNetwork

var fbInstreamAdView: FBInstreamAdView?
open var fbInstreamPlacementID:String? {
        willSet {
            // ToDo
        }
        didSet {
            // if I comment this line is work.
            fbInstreamAdView = FBInstreamAdView.init(placementID: fbInstreamPlacementID ?? "")
            //
        }
    }
```

In pod file I use googleIMA also because I have some videos are do not present ads from facebook.

```
target 'MyAppPlayer' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Brightcove-Player-Core/dynamic'
  pod 'Brightcove-Player-IMA'
  pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'AlamofireImage'
  pod 'CryptoSwift' , '~> 0.15.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.2.0'
  pod 'RealmSwift' #, '~> 2.8.3'
  pod 'KDCircularProgress'
  pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git'
  pod 'VisualEffectView' , '~> 3.1.1'

  #  post_install do |installer|
  #      installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
  #          configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
  #      end
  #  end

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This error in Xcode console.

```
2019-04-30 17:45:37.175508+0700 BBTVBC_Sample[57504:3840076] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FBFinalClassViolationException', reason: 'FBAdUtility is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdUtility'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001118771bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011786e735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   BBTVBC_Sample                       0x000000010fbadb2e +[FBAdUtility initializeAudienceNetwork] + 0
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011786f2fe CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011786f691 _class_initialize + 270
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000117876248 lookUpImpOrForward + 196
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000117883814 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    7   BBTVBC_Sample                       0x000000010fbafd3d -[NSDictionary(FBAdUtility) objectForKeyOrNil:ofClass:] + 271
    8   BBTVBC_Sample                       0x000000010fbaf42b -[NSDictionary(FBAdUtility) stringForKeyOrNil:] + 76
    9   BBTVBCPlayer                        0x0000000117334853 __62-[FBAdEventManager sendRequestInternal:withExtraData:onRetry:]_block_invoke.443 + 462
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118e13595 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118e14602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118e1bb0b _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 791
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118e1c784 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118e2689a _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 733
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000119204611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001192043fd start_wqthread + 13
)
2019-04-30 17:45:37.308791+0700 BBTVBC_Sample[57504:3840104] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C10.1:2][0x7fecce528b70] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-04-30 17:45:37.308994+0700 BBTVBC_Sample[57504:3840104] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C10.1:2][0x7fecce528b70] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-04-30 17:45:37.310010+0700 BBTVBC_Sample[57504:3840104] TIC Read Status [10:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-30 17:45:37.310468+0700 BBTVBC_Sample[57504:3840104] TIC Read Status [10:0x0]: 1:57
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How to fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you creating subclass of FBAdUtility somewhere?

Comment: @sanman nope.
I follow up FBAudienceNetwork example.
Inside this project not have too.

If need to create, please tell me where or how to create. Thank you